# How to make a container div inside a scrollable area get the size of its children?

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable area inside which there are a div and a collection of smaller divs.
[image]

The yellow container takes the width of the visible viewport of the scrollable area.
How do I make it "wrap" the whole set of pink rectangles automatically like how it happens in a regular non-overflow div?

https://codepen.io/sergeibasharov/pen/mdEdKWO

```
<div class="scroll-area">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
  </div>
</div>

.scroll-area{
  background: gray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto
}
.header{
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cell{
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: display:inline-flex;min-width:100% to the yellow

Answer (score -1):

To wrap children of an element with `display: flex`, use `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
.scroll-area{
  background: gray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto
}
.header{
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell{
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-area">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
    <div class="cell">7</div>
    <div class="cell">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```